# Problem pasting text into Inkscape

Tags: text, inkscape

When I try to paste bigger text into Inkscape, it splits it into small parts and it's impossible to put them together. I can't change font type or anything in whole text at once without rewriting it. Is there any option to prevent this splitting and pasting whole text as a one part?

Comment: From which program do you copy-paste?

Comment: I have this problem too. From chrome, notepad & wordpad. It's quite a lot of text and it just says "nothing to paste"

Answer (score 9):

As of Inkscape 0.91, there is actually a place to copy/paste plain text to get around this problem.

1. Create or select the text frame
   If it is *not* a text flow, you need to type of placeholder text too.
2. On the **Text** menu, click **Text and Font**
3. On the **Text** tab, paste the text you want into the box.
4. Click **Apply**.

The reason for the original issue is (I'm guessing) how Inkscape was interpreting new lines.

It's sometimes not just the text that gets copied but other information too, like formatting data and such. Given the purpose of Inkscape (design), I'm always reluctant to just copy/paste something. There could be--for example--extra spaces somewhere, or what I thought was one character was actually something else. For pasting large blocks of text, using the Text and Font window (or editing the XML directly) is the best way to go.

Answer (score 3):

If you are pasting from writing softwares like word.

1. copy text from word and paste it in inkscape & select that object
2. right click on it and select ungroup
3. now your all text is split but its editable and font can be changed.
4. to prevent splitting, first paste it in notepad like apps [notepad++ recommended] then copy all text and paste it in inkscape text box object.
   this method works for paragraphs and plain text. 
   tables do not get properly copied in this.

Answer (score 3):

**A SVG file is a plain XML file in text.**

- Create a text boundary box in Inkscape with the Text tool
- Type some text in it like "Copy Text Here"
- Save the file
- Open the file in a XML editor such as Notepad ++ Look for the following line:

  ```
   id="flowPara4983">Copy Text Here</flowPara></flowRoot>  </g>
  ```
- Replace the "Copy Text Here" with your copied text
- Save the file and reopen in Inkscape.

That's all folks.

Note: Be carefull if you already have done a lot of work.  Rather open another instance of Inkscape, do the exercise there and copy the text into the original.

Comment: Inkscape has an XML editor built in so you should just be able to do it there

Comment: Yes, you can do it with the XML Editor in Inkscape (Ctrl + Shift + X), but I would actually use the *Font and Text* tool though (Ctrl + Shift + T). There is a place there to copy  and paste text, which should solve this problem. I think that feature might not have been available when this question was asked.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy the text, go to Inkscape and click on the text icon

[image]

Then create a box where you can type in and paste it there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy your text
2. Open windows notepad
3. Past your text in notepad
4. Copy the text in notepad
5. Start a text in inkscape
6. Past there. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by deleting all carriage returns / new lines in the text (in notepad) before copying and then reintroducing them after pasting into Inkscape.

Pretty sure this is about how Inksape handles new lines, I don't have a fix, just a workaround. It should probably be reported as a bug to the Inkscape project.